# Pass Javascript variable to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onload

I am new to AngularJS and JavaScript in general and need some help trying get a JavaScript variable into my AngularJS controller. Here is my html page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="test">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <!--Third party scripts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <!--Custom scripts-->
        <script type=" text/javascript" src="app/test.js"></script>
        <!--Third party style sheets-->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="page" ng-controller="PageCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-click="print(gBool)"><a href="#print">Print</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var gBool = false;
    window.onload = function () {
        gBool = true;
    };
</script>
```

Here is the AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('PageCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.print = function (boolParam) {
            console.log(boolParam);
    };
}]);
```

This just prints out 'undefined' in the console when it executes. Is this something that should work?

Comment: if its really needed..make them globally available..

Comment: @Rich If you're making the whole app angular (html ng-app) then why not do it the angular way?

Comment: If you're dealing with a global variable, why do you need to even pass it in as a parameter, why can't you just look up it's value when the function is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it in the "angular" way by using $window:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window)     {
  $scope.memId = $window.memId;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
<li ng-click="print(gBool)"><a href="#print">Print</a></li>
```

You are referencing a variable gBool in your scope, so its `$scope.gBool`
If you define in your JavaScript instead in your html, will work.

```
$scope.gBool = true;
```

Also, lookup `$window` and use it from your controller like this:

```
app.controller('PageCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, '$window') {
    $scope.gBool = false;
    $window.onload = function() {
        $scope.gBool = true;
    };
    $scope.print = function (boolParam) {
            console.log(boolParam);
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two Things to focus

(i)You need to initialize the variable you can use the [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)
(ii) Declare a function to assign the bool value initially

Here is the working [`Application`](http://plnkr.co/edit/2xGPNmkdlLz4bzjxuhvj?p=preview)